# EclEmma not working

Tags: eclipse, eclemma

I'm trying to use EclEmma with Eclipse, but I can't get it to work. I can't see the button that's supposed to launch my project in Coverage mode, There;s also no such option in Run menu:[image]

I've tried to fix it in two ways I've found on the Internet, and none worked:

- the EclEmma help page says that I should enable the Coverage command group on the Commands tab in the Customize Perspective dialog, but there's no such tab in the dialog and no Coverage command group in existing tabs
- I tried to find “Java Code Coverage” in Window > Preferences > General > Appearance > Label Decorators menu - not there

I'm using Eclipse Mars.2 Release (4.5.2) on Windows 10, I have EclEmma v. 2.3.3.201602231923 (according to Help > About Eclipse > Installation Details) installed via Eclipse Marketplace. I have no idea how to fix it, I'll appreciate any help.

Comment: Could you please check - maybe Eclipse Error Log shows some errors? Also you can try on a fresh installation of Eclipse Mars.

Comment: I had a similar issue with Eclipse 4.6.1 (neon), but it's **all fixed ** in 4.6.2

Comment: Also not working for neon.2 4.6.2

Answer (score 0):

In eclipse 4.9 (2018-9) the option to enable the "Coverage as ..." command can be found in "Customizing Perspective" (rightclick on the perspective shortcut), then on tab page "Action Set Availability": Click the "Java Code Coverage" option.

Another problem I encountered: Although the "Coverage as..." command was available, there was no result visible at the end in the view "Coverage". The problem can be solved by following the advice from the [eclEmma FAQ](https://www.eclemma.org/faq.html#trouble04):

> **The Coverage view stays empty and there is no source highlighting. Why?**
>
> In Eclipse preferences there is an option Launch in debug mode when workspace contains breakpoints under Run/Debug → Launching. If this option is enabled and there are breakpoints in your workspace coverage mode will not work, because it is automatically replaced with debug mode. Set this option to Never if you want to run code coverage analysis.

BTW: I am using eclEmma plugin 3.1.2